# Restsharp return IEnumerable of type T

Tags: generics, ienumerable, restsharp

I'm trying to create a generic GET method for my web api's using RestSharp.

```
public  IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string url, DataFormat ReturnFormat )
{
   RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET) { RequestFormat = ReturnFormat };
   return _restClient.Execute<IEnumerable<T>>(request);
}
```

But the last line has the error

> Error 2   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'RestSharp.RestClient.Execute(RestSharp.IRestRequest)'

I think the issue is the return type of IEnumerable but wondered if it would workd if i placed some kind of restraint on the return type ?  If so what ?

Ok..i just changed the code to this

```
        public  IEnumerable<T> GetData<T>(string url, DataFormat ReturnFormat )
    {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET) { RequestFormat = ReturnFormat };
        var a = _restClient.Execute<List<string>>(request);

        return (IEnumerable<T>)a.Data;

    }
```

It compiles.  Not sure if it works ...but why is it happy now ?

Comment: How are you expecting the client to specify a generic type argument? Perhaps you should have another parameter specifying the type name, and just make the return type `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

It's happy because `Execute<T>` has a [`new()` constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) on the type argument. This simply means that `T` must be a concrete type with a parameterless constructor or the compiler will complain. Presumably the implementation of `Execute<T>` does something like `result = new T();`, and the `new()` contraint ensures that the type can be instantiated in this manner. If you just provide an interface for `T`, there's no way it can know how to construct a concrete instance. The `new()` constraint prevents that by catching it at compile time.